# Auto insert words from one cell to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to get Excel to automatically insert a word into a list if it's been selected elsewhere

[image: Image showing what I'm working with]

Trying to get it so that if a company is chosen in the section for a day then it auto shows up in the list of weekly company totals(we don't want to show companies that don't have any value against them).

Comment: Welcome to Superuser . Can you please make it a tiny bit clearer, the specific ranges? Is it that any company shown in column `C` you want to show in `W` and a total for it in `X`?

Comment: To note, the structure of the sheet isn't very good. Having names of days and repeated headers in the middle of columns makes it difficult to do anything with the columns' data (as the Monday, Tuesday, and Company are also in coulmn C). Can you reorganize the sheet to be more streamlined?

Comment: Hi, yes that's correct for your first question regarding the column letters. Unfortunately the guy I'm doing it for wanted it in much the same layout as the physical diary he had so I'm limited in the changes I can make to the way it looks. Are there any simple streamlining things you could think of please?

Comment: Simple streamlining would mean that every row in a column includes one type of data, that's how a spreadsheet should typically be. Maybe take out the days of the week to a new column on the left of the Company name column and don't repeat the column headers (you can freeze the first row, so you always see what columns are what when scrolling down). Same with the week total, it should not start on `W14` but on `W1` and if you want another totals thing make it in Y & Z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`UNIQUE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/unique-function-c5ab87fd-30a3-4ce9-9d1a-40204fb85e1e) function to get a list of company names from columns `C`, one per company name. But given that your column `C` is interrupted with the names of the day and the headers, you'll also need to filter out each of those:

I think this in `W14` should work (make sure that all the cells under that are empty so the result can spilliver to the cells it will fill:

`=SORT(UNIQUE(FILTER(C:C,(C:C<>"")*(C:C<>"Company")*(C:C<>"Monday")*(C:C<>"Tuesday")*(C:C<>"Wednesday")*(C:C<>"Thursday")*(C:C<>"Friday"))))`

Comment: Appreciated, thank you :)